# pyodbc connect to database twice and failed

Tags: python, sql-server, connection, pyodbc

I'm trying use Python and `pyodbc` to access SQL server 2008. The first connection works. Then, after the program finishes its job, it closes the connection. When the program tries to access the database and connect to it again, it fails in the statement:

```
self.conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=self.DRIVER, SERVER=self.SERVER, DATABASE=self.DATABASE, UID=self.UID, PWD=self.PWD, charset="UTF-8")
```

but the first time is OK. So does anyone know why? Below is the Python code:

```
class ODBC_MS:  

    def __init__(self, DRIVER,SERVER, DATABASE, UID, PWD):
        ''' initialization '''

        self.DRIVER = DRIVER
        self.SERVER = SERVER
        self.DATABASE = DATABASE
        self.UID = UID
        self.PWD = PWD


    def _GetConnect(self):
        ''' Connect to the DB '''
        if not self.DATABASE:
            raise(NameError,"no getting db name")
        try:
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=self.DRIVER, SERVER=self.SERVER,
                                       DATABASE=self.DATABASE, UID=self.UID,
                                       PWD=self.PWD, charset="UTF-8")
        except Exception,e:
            print e.message
        else:
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
            if not self.cur:
                raise(NameError,"connected failed!")
            else:
                return self.cur, self.conn

    def ExecNoQuery(self,conn, cursor, sql):
        cursor.execute(sql)
        ret = conn.commit()
        return ret

    def _UnConnect(self,conn, cursor):
        conn.close()


    if __name__ == '__main__':

    ms = ODBC_MS('{SQL SERVER}', r'<server>', '<db>', '<user>',  '<password>') 
    cursor, conn = ms._GetConnect() #connection

    sql = "create table XX for example"

    ret = ms.ExecNoQuery(conn, cursor,sql) #sql operation


    ms._UnConnect(conn, cursor) #close db


    #access the database the second time.
    ms = ODBC_MS('{SQL SERVER}', r'<server>', '<db>', '<user>',  '<password>') 
    cursor, conn = ms._GetConnect() # not success, I don't know why

    sql = "create table XX for example"
    ret = ms.ExecNoQuery(conn, cursor,sql) #sql operation

    ms._UnConnect(conn, cursor) #close db
```

The second time when the program calls `ms.GetConnect()`, the statement `self.conn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER=self.DRIVER, SERVER=self.SERVER, DATABASE=self.DATABASE, UID=self.UID, PWD=self.PWD, charset="UTF-8")` fails.

Comment: Your code works fine here after adding the pyodbc import and fixing identation of class methods. Please update your question with full stack trace of the exception received.

Comment: I'd love to hear an update from you @Leo if you solved the issue. I notice similar behavior but on the second call to execute.